# How to use all the empty space in UI to fill with text

Tags: swift, swiftui

I cannot figure out why my text is cutting off in the middle, instead of using the whole space in the green rectangle. What am I missing?

[image]

the text is stored here

```
if let title = content.title {
    Text(title)
        .font(.system(size: 12))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .lineLimit(5)
}
```

I tried adding `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` but that did not do anything.

Here is my full `ContentView` code.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                Button("Clear") {
                    viewModel.clearHistory()
                }
                .font(.system(size: 12))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                .padding(.vertical, 2)
                .background(Color.red)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .frame(width: 100, alignment: .leading)
                
                ForEach(viewModel.contents) { content in
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
                        if let urlString = content.imageThumbnail {
                            ImageView(urlString: urlString)
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
                        }
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                            HStack {
                                if let profilePicURLString = content.userProfilePic {
                                    ImageView(urlString: profilePicURLString)
                                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                        .clipShape(Circle())
                                }
                                if let username = content.username {
                                    Text(username)
                                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            }
                            
                            if let title = content.title {
                                Text(title)
                                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .lineLimit(5)
                                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                            HStack(spacing: 5) {
                                if let title = content.title {
                                    Button(action: {
                                        UIPasteboard.general.string = title
                                    }) {
                                        Text("Copy")
                                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                                            .padding(.vertical, 2)
                                            .background(Color.blue)
                                            .cornerRadius(8)
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                Button(action: {
                                    if let videoSrc = content.videoSrc, let url = URL(string: videoSrc) {
                                        videoDownloader.downloadVideo(from: url)
                                    }
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "arrow.down.circle.fill")
                                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding([.horizontal, .top])
        }
        
        HStack {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .fill(Color(red: 0.15, green: 0.15, blue: 0.15))
                TextField("Enter URL", text: $urlString)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
                    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                    .padding(.vertical, 8)
            }
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 0.5))
            .frame(height: 36)
            
            Button("Load") {
                viewModel.loadPage(urlString: urlString)
                urlString = ""
            }
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .padding(.vertical, 8)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .frame(height: 36)
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
    .padding(.vertical)
    .background(Color(red: 0.15, green: 0.15, blue: 0.15))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your copy and download buttons are in the same HStack with the title. Comment out these copy button and download button codes to see different. To fix it, nested these buttons within HStack of username and profile image, also remove some `Spacer` and reduce bound HStack spacing to 0.

```swift
HStack {
    if let profilePicURLString = content.userProfilePic {
        ImageView(urlString: profilePicURLString)
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .clipShape(Circle())
    }
    if let username = content.username {
        Text(username)
            .font(.system(size: 12))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    
    Spacer()

    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
        HStack(spacing: 5) {
            if let title = content.title {
                Button(action: {
                    UIPasteboard.general.string = title
                }) {
                    Text("Copy")
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                        .padding(.vertical, 2)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                if let videoSrc = content.videoSrc, let url = URL(string: videoSrc) {
                    videoDownloader.downloadVideo(from: url)
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.down.circle.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output here:

[image]

Comment: That was it, I was able to update it and now its as expected, thank you a lot, gave you upvote.

Comment: Glad I could help.